# Flutter layout, alignment, page controller, and how to make OnboardingScreen only one time?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i'm working on project for my university project and i'm having a problem.

First, i wanna add a back to my onboarding screen but i already use align for "next" on the bottom right while i want the back in the bottom left

Second, i wanna make the title (welcome,purpose,creator) in the middle, but i cannot put it in the center because i'm using a sizedbox

Third, i want the onboarding screen to only appear once, so when a user who have open it won't see it again (basically the first time opening, onboardingscreen but the second time straight to homepage)

sorry for my english
photo if you wanna visualize:
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwt1q.png)
Here are the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import '../home_screen.dart';

class Onboarding extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OnboardingScreen createState() => _OnboardingScreen();
}

class _OnboardingScreen extends State<Onboarding> {
  final int _numPages = 3;
  final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  int _currentPage = 0;

  List<Widget> _buildPageIndicator() {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < _numPages; i++) {
      list.add(i == _currentPage ? _indicator(true) : _indicator(false));
    }
    return list;
  }

  Widget _indicator(bool isActive) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      height: 8.0,
      width: isActive ? 24.0 : 16.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isActive ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF7B51D3),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              stops: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9],
              colors: [
                Colors.black,
                Color(0xff112339),
                Color(0xff112339),
                Colors.black,
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Skip',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 600.0,
                  child: PageView(
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _pageController,
                    onPageChanged: (int page) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentPage = page;
                      });
                    },
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:70.0,left: 40.0,right: 40.0,),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/Logo.png',
                                ),
                                height: 120.0,
                                width: 120.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                            Text(
                              'Welcome',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 21.0,
                                height: 1.5,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Welcome to Moviez, the place where you will spend your time magically',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                height: 1.2,
                                fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:70.0,left: 40.0,right: 40.0,),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/Logo.png',
                                ),
                                height: 120.0,
                                width: 120.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                            Text(
                              'Purpose',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 21.0,
                                height: 1.5,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'This App is for educational purposes only',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                height: 1.2,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:70.0,left: 40.0,right: 40.0,),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'assets/images/Logo.png',
                                ),
                                height: 120.0,
                                width: 120.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                            Text(
                              'Creator',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 21.0,
                                height: 1.5
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Adela, Caroline, Cordellya, David, Valentino',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                height: 1.2,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: _buildPageIndicator(),
                ),
                _currentPage != _numPages - 1
                    ? Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _pageController.nextPage(
                                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                curve: Curves.ease,
                              );
                            },
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Next',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 22.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.arrow_forward,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 30.0,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Text(''),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: _currentPage == _numPages - 1
          ? Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: GestureDetector(
               onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                );
                },
                child: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Get started',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF5B16D0),
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : Text(''),
    );
  }
}
```

here is my main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/screens/home_screen/widgets/onboard.dart';
import 'screens/home_screen/home_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
  Paint.enableDithering = true;
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Movie App',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                bodyText1: TextStyle(
                  // fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                  // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 22,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                button: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 30),
          )),
      home: Onboarding(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your first point:
Assuming that you want the "back" button on the same row as the "next" one, I would suggest you edit your `Row` widget as follows.

```
Row(children: [
  Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
  Text('Back'),
  Spacer(),
  Text('Next'),
  Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
])
```

I've used two `Text` widgets just to show you how it would look. In your app, you can use two different buttons with different text and different `onTap` or `onPressed` methods. You can check the `Button` section of [this page](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/material) to learn more about the different buttons available in Flutter.

Second: I think that all you have to do to have your titles centered on the screen is to change the `crossAxisAlignment` property of the related `Column` form `CrossAxisAlignment.start` to `CrossAxisAlignment.center`

Comment: As for the third one, I would suggest posting it as a separate question.

Comment: the second point is correct, thanks i thought it would change the entire text including the bottom one. 
and answering to the first point what about the pagecontroller? if i do that isn't both button will do nextpage? cmiiw i'm new to flutter

Comment: I edited my answer to answer your questions

Comment: hey, i'm sorry for the late reply, am not very active on stackoverflow and yes it does helped me. thank you once again and am very sorry for the late reply